# What's a soft-edged look?

Tags: vocabulary

> The issue was that Kirk was falling for her. She could see it in the
>   soft-edged, goofy way he looked at her when he thought that she wasn’t
>   paying attention.

What is this soft-edged way Kirk looks at her?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What is described looks somewhat like this:
[image: Boy and girl in a classroom, looking at each other in adoration]

The phrase *soft edged* refers to the relaxation of facial muscles, "softening" the features. Also, there is technique in old movies, where romantic scenes and close-ups of the heroine were "blurred" a bit.

Comment: Can it philosophically refer to soft edges in painting as well? I think so, since soft edges present peacefulness (usually) and Kirk has "peace" towards her.